# Doctrine with static entities

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine-orm

I have a database, where I store some fixed values like product categories. When I create a new product and I want to assign a category to it, I do it this way:

```
$categories = new ProductCategoryRepository();
$category = $categories->find(ProductCategory::EXAMPLE);

$product = new Product();
$product->setCategory($category);
```

However, I'm not sure why I have to lookup the database all the time to get static entities my app is already aware of.

It should be enough to assign the category statically. Maybe something like this:

```
$category = ProductCategory::EXAMPLE;
```

Now Doctrine should persist the relation with the correct ID (described by the ProductCategory class (which could be an entity?)) and I no longer have to lookup the database for static properties.

I don't know how to do this, yet. I could create new entities all the time, but this doesn't seem to be correct, because the values are already stored in the DB and they are always the same and **not** new entities.

```
$category = new ProductCategory::EXAMPLE;
```

Fetching the relation from the product however should return the property as an entity:

```
$category = $product->getCategory();

return $category instanceof ProductCategory; // true
```

Is there a way to achieve this behaviour?

It is more an architecture question than a performance tweak. I don't want to describe information multiple times (db entries, php constants, entity relations etc.).

Comment: The Doctrine ORM layer deals with objects so I think you are pretty much stuck using category objects.  There however a EntityManager::getReference('ProductCategory',$id) method which returns a reference category object containing only the id.  So it reduces the data being transferred.   http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/advanced-configuration.html#reference-proxies

Answer (score 0):

There is something called "second level cache" in Doctrine, but the feature is considered experimental and you should maybe read the documentation carefully before using it.
A quote from [the official documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/second-level-cache.html) of this feature:

> ### The Second Level Cache
>
> The second level cache functionality is marked as experimental for now. It is a very complex feature and we cannot guarantee yet that it works stable in all cases.

Entity cache definition is done like this: ([documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/second-level-cache.html#entity-cache-definition))

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Cache(usage="READ_ONLY", region="my_entity_region")
 */
```

---

To improve performance for such entities like you are talking about in your question you should also consider to mark them as "read only", which will lead to performance increase from Doctrine 2.1, as can be found in [the Doctrine documentation on improving performance](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/improving-performance.html#read-only-entities):

> ### Read-Only Entities
>
> Starting with Doctrine 2.1 you can mark entities as read only (See metadata mapping references for details). This means that the entity marked as read only is never considered for updates, which means when you call flush on the EntityManager these entities are skipped even if properties changed. Read-Only allows to persist new entities of a kind and remove existing ones, they are just not considered for updates.

The entity should be configured like this: ([documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html#entity))

```
/** @Entity(readOnly=true) */
```

---

### Second level cache and read only for your ProductCategory:

So after setting up second level read only caching with for example a region named `read_only_entity_region` your configuration for your `ProductCategory` would look something like this:

```
/**
 * @Entity(readOnly=true)
 * @Cache(usage="READ_ONLY", region="read_only_entity_region")
 */
class ProductCategory 
{
    //...your entity definition...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want it to hit the database every time you could just store it in the Cache:

```
public function getCategory(){
    return Cache::rememberForever('category-'.$this->category_id, function() {
        return $categories->find($this->category_id);
    });
}
```

This will pull the info from the database if it has never been pulled, but will just grab it from the cache if it has been.  You would have to use `Cache::forget('category-2')` to remove it, or `php artisan cache:clear`.  Your static values would just be integer IDs and your products would have a `category_id` but the categories themselves would be cached.

Comment: Have you actually tried this with Doctrine entities?  Typically, entities need to be "managed" by the entity manager.  References are stored in an internal unit of work object.  Creating an existing object outside of the entity manager seldom ends well.  Though maybe Laravel works around this somehow.

Comment: admittedly i do not know about that, but i know the Laravel cache supports caching objects and handles the serialization.